# Do I get experience if I flee from King Slime?

Tags: battle-chasers-nightwar

In the King Slime fight, the one in the Well, I believe it is a hunt as well

Can I kill a bunch of the summoned slimes then flee with the party and get exp? Do I still get the exp if I fled? I already killed in my game but I would like to know for NG+

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, you cannot flee from a hunt boss therefore cannot kill minion slimes then flee. Whatever 3 main character you choose would ideally be your 3 main characters.